How to implement Reader-Writer pattern in Rust?
I want to implement Writer-Reader pattern decoupled with a Channel. The problem is that Rust allows only 1 mutable reference at a time, but Writer must be able to write to the channel and Reader must be able to remove a value that it just read. Is there a conceptual violation of Rust assumptions?
Here is the code that expectedly can't be compiled:
// Channel
struct Channel {
    queue: Vec<String>
}

impl Channel {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            queue: vec!()
        }
    }

    fn write(&mut self, value: &str) {
        self.queue.push(value.to_string());
    }

    fn read(&mut self) -> Option<String> {
        if !self.queue.is_empty() {
            Some(self.queue.remove(self.queue.len() - 1))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

// Writer

struct Writer<'a> {
    channel: &'a mut Channel
}

impl<'a> Writer<'a> {
    fn new(channel: &'a mut Channel) -> Self {
        Self {
            channel
        }
    }

    fn write(&mut self, value: &str) {
        self.channel.write(value);
    }
}

// Reader

struct Reader<'a> {
    channel: &'a mut Channel
}

impl<'a> Reader<'a> {
    fn new(channel: &'a mut Channel) -> Self {
        Self {
            channel
        }
    }

    fn read(&mut self) {
        if let Some(value) = self.channel.read() {
            print!("Read {}", value)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut channel = Channel::new();
    let mut writer = Writer::new(&mut channel);
    let mut reader = Reader::new(&mut channel); // cannot borrow `channel` as mutable more than once at a time
    writer.write("test_value");
    reader.read();
}

Playground
What's the right way of doing that in Rust?
PS. It's mean to be executed in single-thread environment.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/channels.html

There should be no problem with wrapping the channel in a RefCell if its for a single-threaded environment. By doing that you can mutate values behind an immutable reference &self -> self.channel.borrow_mut().func()

@DanielA.White Thanks, but that's just naming coincidence. I could name it Pipe for instance to avoid confusion

@kmdreko Thanks, but i'm wondering is there way to have compile-time check and whether Rust assumption is 'fair' or 'reasonable' at all? With RefCell i feel like fighting with the system that was meant to help instead

Even if your code doesn't have any evident problems from multiple mutable references, if Rust accepted your code it wouldn't be able to save you from when it is a problem. The rules are there for a reason.

Having multiple resources mutate a shared object is one case that Rust doesn't allow without some helper type to guarantee it is safe (RefCell, Mutex, etc.) or by using unsafe in which case it is on you to provide that guarantee. You could use unsafe in this case if the burden of a RefCell is too much, but unsafe code is easy to get wrong so I advise against it.

This goes a bit out off topic, but it seems in this trivial case Rust philosophy plays agains dev as 1) it does not add a safety 2) forces to fight against the system to still do what is needed. At the end the responsibility is still up to the dev (eg. have to use Mutex), but it causes additional efforts to make it compilable for no reason (knowing it's a single-threaded app)

To elaborate: single-threaded code is NOT immune to memory errors. Your code could easily be extended with a method that returns a reference to data from the channel (like a .peek() method) that could lead to memory errors since that it could be held while the other reader/writer mutates the channel and invalidate the reference.

@4ntoine Proving to the compiler that your code does not have memory safety issues is not "playing against devs" nor is it correct that it "does not add safety." There are plenty of ways that Rust's rules protect you from doing memory-unsafe things even in single-threaded code. Take this trivial example: let mut v = vec![42]; let x = &v[0]; v.clear(); println!("{x}");. Rust does give you an escape hatch (interior mutability) which moves the rule enforcement to runtime. To be honest, your comment sounds a lot like "I should be able to use Rust without learning the Rust way to do things."

@cdhowie That's exactly what i asked: "what's the rust way of doing that?" In your trivial example locking vec from mutability is excessive. We know it will be changed at some point, so the code should be written in the way that is ready for it. To be more detailed, &[0] can't be used because we can not move this responsibility to the compiler to guarantee that. But thank you for the explanation.

The Rust way of doing things is to create safe-to-use abstractions. And that's exactly what you can do here with a RefCell. A simple-to-use type that is also error-proof. Spreading borrow[_mut]() across the code is bad and seldom needed, but what you do here cannot panic as it is encapsulated well. In a general-purpose library, I would use UnsafeCell and unsafe to avoid the overhead if needed; unless you do need that overhead avoided, you can safely use a RefCell.

The static analysis performed by the borrow-checker follows the same rules as the Reader-Writer pattern: many readers of a resource are allowed at the same time, but as soon as (and as long as) a writer accesses this resource, no other reader or writer can access it. The borrow-checker enforces these rules at compile-time, thus it can prove these assumptions are correct only if the structure (in the sense of structural) of the program is made so.
However, there are programs where we want to share a common resource between many places in the code, and it cannot be proven by a static analysis that these multiple usages won't conflict (with respect to the above rules). That's where interior-mutability come into play: the idea is to enforce these exact same rules at runtime (at the expense of a minimal cost). (the same exists in a parallel context with the usual read-write locks)
Back to your example, you want to keep at the same time two references (reader and writer) to the same resource (channel) and use them freely to alter the common resource. Then, the references need fundamentally to be shared. As shown on this question, the & and &mut notations are often seen as const and mutable references (as a shorthand), but the real meaning should be though about in terms of shared or exclusive references. We must think in these shared/exclusive terms first, and the const/mutable aspect is only the consequence of this design choice.
Although your example uses the terms read and write, it does not match the usual reader-writer pattern. Actually, these two operations are two different mutations of the underlying resource; they can be considered as two writers. A reader operation would be simply testing emptiness or getting the size.
Please find below your example rewritten using RefCell in order to rely on interior-mutability. Note that, in these conditions, the references can actually be shared (&, not &mut) as required by your intended usage of reader and writer. The usages of reader and writer are intertwined so that the borrow-checker would find this conflictual if we used exclusive references.
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Channel {
    queue: RefCell<Vec<String>>,
}
impl Channel {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            queue: RefCell::new(vec![]),
        }
    }

    fn write(
        &self,
        value: &str,
    ) {
        self.queue.borrow_mut().push(value.to_string());
    }

    fn read(&self) -> Option<String> {
        self.queue.borrow_mut().pop()
    }
}

struct Writer<'a> {
    channel: &'a Channel,
}
impl<'a> Writer<'a> {
    fn new(channel: &'a Channel) -> Self {
        Self { channel }
    }

    fn write(
        &self,
        value: &str,
    ) {
        self.channel.write(value);
    }
}

struct Reader<'a> {
    channel: &'a Channel,
}
impl<'a> Reader<'a> {
    fn new(channel: &'a Channel) -> Self {
        Self { channel }
    }

    fn read(&self) {
        if let Some(value) = self.channel.read() {
            println!("Read {}", value)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let channel = Channel::new();
    let writer = Writer::new(&channel);
    let reader = Reader::new(&channel);
    writer.write("first value");
    reader.read();
    writer.write("second value");
    reader.read();
}
/*
Read: first value
Read: second value
*/


is it safe to run in multithread environment?

@4ntoine In a multithreaded context, we usually use Arc<Mutex<T>> or Arc<RwLock<T>> (in order to distinguish read/write accesses). We can get rid of Arc if we use scoped threads.
